# How can I use tab_parent/tab_root in hook_menu to have one router item appear as a local task for another router item with a different path?

Tags: 7, routes

Say I have the path `widget/123` to view a widget, and have another path to edit some properties of this widget at `admin/acme/widget/123/edit`. In `hook_menu` it looks like I can still have the admin path appear as a local task (tab) by setting the `tab_parent` and `tab_root` properties in `hook_menu()`, but I can't seem to get it to work. I know how to setup `widget/%/edit` as a local task, but in this case I'm only interested in setting a different "root" path as a local task.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

function acme_menu() {

  // View a widget.
  $items['widget/%'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'acme_widget_view',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'acme_widget_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1, 'view'),
    'file' => 'includes/widget.view.inc',
  );

  // Edit a widget.
  $items['admin/acme/widget/%/edit'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'tab_parent' => 'widget/%',
    'tab_root' => 'widget/%',
    'title' => 'Edit Widget',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('acme_widget_edit', 3),
    'access callback' => 'acme_widget_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1, 'edit'),
    'file' => 'includes/widget.edit.inc',
  );

  return $items;
}

?>
```

Am I misunderstanding tab_parent/root, or can this be done?

**Update:** I was missing a `MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAK_TASK`. Adding

```
$items['widget/%/view'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK, 
    'title' => 'View'
);
```

allows the tabs to appear. However, they don't share the same argument position and so the argument (the widget ID) isn't passed between the two. The 'Edit' tab, for example, links to `admin/acme/widget//edit`. Is there a way to have different routes like this and pass the argument position around?

Comment: That looks right - but in order to invoke tabs, you need more than one in the parent path. Usually you'd have something like `$items['widget/%/view']` as well, which is a `MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK`, and becomes a sibling of the other `MENU_LOCAL_TASK`s under the same parent. At the moment I think the fact you've only got a single local task under the parent means that none will show

Comment: @Clive I wanted to post something similar as an answer, but you are first... only why as a mere comment?

Comment: @Mołot It's just a theory, I haven't had time to check if it's true (sounds logical but this is Drupal, you never know!) Do feel free to put the answer in

Comment: @Clive now when you said that... will need to test :P I'll try to test it tomorrow, no way I'll be able to do this today.

Comment: That's it, Clive! Adding this item solved it: `$items['widget/%/view'] = array('type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK, 'title' => 'View');`. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually, Clive, the argument isn't available to the 'edit' tab – it just links to admin/acme/widget//edit. Any thoughts there?

Comment: I would add that if you have a loader wildcard (ex. `/admin/%node/view`) in the parent path, you should replace it with normal wildcard (ex.  `'parent_tab' => '/admin/%/view'`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken the `tab_root` and `tab_parent` properties need to point to a path prefix of the router item in question - at least if there are wildcards on the path. The code responsible for this restriction is somewhat convoluted, but what you find when stepping through it is the following:

When generating the tab-links, the `_menu_translate` function is responsible for replacing the %-wildcards with actual values (node-id, etc). However the replacement values are not computed from the actual object-ids but are derived from the current URL. For example when accessing `widget/5`, the object-id is on position 1 and therefore when generating tab-links, the value 5 is only injected into paths having the %-wildcard at position 1.

This also leads to another consequence. When navigating to `admin/acme/widget/5/edit`, you will find that there are no tabs on this page - even if widget number 5 actually exists. This is because when generating the URLs for the other tabs, they will start with `widget/acme` instead of `widget/5` because the value `acme` is at position 1 in the current path.

If you like to provide tabs on your widget page as well as have it in the backend, then simply duplicate the router item. E.g:

```
function acme_menu() {

  // View a widget.
  $items['widget/%'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'acme_widget_view',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'acme_widget_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1, 'view'),
    'file' => 'includes/widget.view.inc',
  );

  $items['widget/%/view'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'title' => 'View'
  );

  // Edit a widget - frontend
  $items['widget/%/edit'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'title' => 'Edit Widget',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('acme_widget_edit', 1),
    'access callback' => 'acme_widget_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1, 'edit'),
    'file' => 'includes/widget.edit.inc',
  );

  // Edit a widget - backend
  $items['admin/acme/widget/%/edit'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'title' => 'Edit Widget',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('acme_widget_edit', 3),
    'access callback' => 'acme_widget_access',
    'access arguments' => array(3, 'edit'),
    'file' => 'includes/widget.edit.inc',
  );

  return $items;
}
```

If you like to move around stuff from a third-party module, you still can implement additional router-items on behalf of it in a custom module - or even move them using `hook_menu_alter`.

Comment: Thanks znerol. I ended up doing something similar to this, i.e. duplicating the `widget/%` item, and leaving all other items at the admin path. I think I'll use a `user_access`/`drupal_goto` to send proper users to `admin/acme/widget/%` if they visit `widget/%`.